Centering entire main element
I have put some content and form inside the main element. Here is the HTML:
<main>
  <h1>My main content</h1>
  <form action="/action_page.php" id="form">
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form> 
</main>

with the following CSS:


main {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
<main>
    <h1>My main content</h1>
    <form action="/action_page.php" id="form">
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</main>



However, the main element is not centered exactly. What could be the reason?

It centers just fine in the snippet (click "Full page" and view it on a window wider than 800 px.) What do you mean by "not centering exactly"? What did you expect to happen?

@Guy when I inspect element, I still see content towards slightly left. should I make width: 100vw; ?

Yes, because you've centered the container, not the content. If you make it wider then the content moves even more left. Either a) make the container smaller so that the content fits more snugly or b) center the contents instead with text-align: center or flexbox or something similar.

Does text-align: center align forms as well ? Also using width: 100vw; introduces horizontal scroll bar. Why is that since 100vw means 100% of viewport width ?

Forms don't have visual representation so that question makes no sense. You get scrollbars because the page body has margins.

It's better not to use 100vw except in specific circumstances as it mean the viewport excluding space for scrollbars. Use 100% instead.

If you add outline: 1px solid #000 to main, you will understand why it's not centered.


main {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;

    outline: 1px solid;
}
<main>
    <h1>My main content</h1>
    <form action="/action_page.php" id="form">
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</main>



The main element takes up 800px no matter how wide the children are so you will always have a lot of white-space to the right of the form.
Change width to max-width and add display: inline-block to have main wrap around the widest child, but you will get another problem instead.


main {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;

    outline: 1px solid;
}
<main>
    <h1>My main content</h1>
    <form action="/action_page.php" id="form">
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</main>



The element wont center anymore, because you can only center using margin: auto on block elements. So add a div.container around the main elements width a max-width and center that instead.


main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
 }

.center-container {
   display: inline;
   max-width: 800px;
   outline: 1px solid; /* ONLY FOR SHOWING THE SIZE OF THE CONTAINER */
}
<main>
    <div class="center-container">
      <h1>My main content</h1>
      <form action="/action_page.php" id="form">
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
   </div>
</main>




Just decrease the width to the width of the form (main's content).  You can check it in the inspector. And change the width to max-width, to make it responsive.


main {
  max-width: 235px; /* it was just width*/
  margin: 0 auto;
}
<main>
  <h1>My main content</h1>
  <form action="/action_page.php" id="form">
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</main>




Since the entire content takes 100% of the main width, centering things will look exactly like non-centering them. Therefore, you can achieve your goal by specifying  a width for the contents of your main in percent (I used 50%) and then specify a margin-left for main that will be half of the unused real-estate in width. (So, if you have chosen your content to be of 50%, then it's a margin-left of (100 - 50) / 2 % = 25%. If, instead you have chosen a width of 80%, then it would be a margin-left of (100 - 80) / 2 % = 10%).


main {
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: 25%;
}

main > * {
    width: 50%;
}
<main>
    <h1>My main content</h1>
    <form action="/action_page.php" id="form">
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</main>



Of course, this can still be improved, but applying further size and other styles to your elements, but this is a good start, I suppose.
